# DP (seating arrangement)

Tags: dynamic-programming

We're given a set of positions P = (p1,p2, .. pn) that are all natural numbers. We're also given a number of chairs Kc and a number of tables Kt.
We consider that too people are uncomfortable sitting in the line near each other unless there's a table between them.

Basically we want to arrange Kc chairs and Kt tables among positions of P so that we minimize discomfort (minimize the max of the distance between any two chairs not separated by a table ).

Any ideas on how to tackle the problem ?
for example, we have positions {1,5,7,11,18,25,33} and at each position we can either put a chair or table or leave it empty. the only condition is that we should place all Kc chairs and all Kt tables.
Hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: does the chairs and tables go only at P?

Comment: It is recommended to add a concrete example to your question.